# Word for a choice that is not really a choice

Tags: phrase-requests

A long time ago, I read an article about wearing or not wearing a hijab. In the article, there was a term that described the fact that while, on paper, there was a choice, that decision would be so heavily influenced by one's culture that it was not really a free choice. So basically, something that is said to be a choice but really isn't.

Does anyone know what that term is? "*Something* choice," maybe?

So, to add more information I think it's more to do with free will. That you think you're making a choice but because that choice is so ingrained with cultural influences that choice is not really freely made. It may not be a common phrase (I've been trying to hunt down the name of this concept for years!), I quite like illusory choice which sort of fits although the illusory bit is not specific to it being culturally determined.

I think illusion of choice may be the phrase I am looking for, I think it will work in other contexts which is what I wanted. There has been a number of times I have wanted to use this concept in an argument about something else but have been unable to phrase it. I'll check out false choice too, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of non-choice you actually mean. Are they being forced/blackmailed to wear a hijab? Have they been conditioned into wearing a hijab without even thinking they have an option? Are the negative consequences so bad that they have no practical choice despite no overt pressure? Or is wearing a hajib so much better that no rational person would choose not to do it?

Comment: There is *de facto* — but that doesn’t really apply to the word *choice* here.

Comment: @StuartF I think the point they're making is that they didn't actually make a choice, it's just something they've always done and continue doing. Similarly, most people don't choose their religion: when you're raised with a faith, you just take it as given.

Comment: I think "an __illusory__ choice" is a great description, but I don't think that's a common set-phrase, which is what you've asked for.

Comment: Are we talking about social and cultural pressure here, or a law?  I think to force a choice is to _corerce_.  There are nuanced words that convey where the force comes from.  For example, _taboo_ may be a good single word for what you are describing, but it's not so focussed on the _choice_ aspect of it, but rather the heavy social influencing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts, but there's a slang term I've heard used before: `voluntold`. It's a combination of `volunteer` and `told`.

Comment: While it isn't as snappy as what you're looking for, a construction like "culturally-sensitive choice" or "culturally-informed choice" might get across the same thing.

Comment: I think "illusion of choice" is the commonly used phrase (instead of "illusory choice"), though that might not be what you're after if you wanted a phrase with cultural implications attached.

Comment: This description seems related to the super-ego: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Super-ego

Comment: You could say it's a _mandate_ or even a _habit_ ("habit" has a double meaning of "a regular behaviour", as well as "an article of headwear"!)

Comment: I think part of the reason you're having trouble finding a suitable word is that the concept is not well defined.  Certainly you haven't conveyed it clearly to me.  What does it mean in this context for a choice to be a "free" one, that makes a culturally-conditioned decision less- or non-"free"?  When you say "you think you're making a choice", do you mean to imply that the chooser is unaware of some or all of the factors influencing their decision?

Comment: Are you looking for a word that that is _specific_ to cultural norms?  Because there are a million things we _could_ choose to do every day, but we don't, because those choices are _obviously terrible_.  I choose not to punch my boss in the face, because I want to _keep_ my job, thank you very much!  Seems to me your hijab example just falls into the broad category of "the right (polite/convenient/effective/habitual) thing to do."

Comment: It's not uncommon to say/hear something like "a choice that's not actually a choice", which makes me think there isn't a single commonly recognized set phrase for this usage. There are lots of good answers here, but if you feel like you haven't found the perfect phrase yet, it's possible it doesn't exist.

Comment: You may be correct. Or the author of the article made up a phrase to describe what she was talking about!

Answer (score 40):

It's [Hobson's Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice).

> A Hobson's choice is a free choice in which only one thing is actually offered. The term is often used to describe an illusion that multiple choices are available. The most well known Hobson's choice is "I'll give you a choice: take it or leave it", wherein "leaving it" is strongly undesirable.

Comment: The example isn't really "Hobson's choice". The idea is that there is no real choice (the alternatives offered are really not different). In "take it or leave it" the two choices are different. It may be that you are being forced into taking one (because the other is not real) but that's not "Hobson's Choice". Ford's "any colour you like as long as it's black" is a much better example.

Comment: (And, yes, I am aware that that you are paraphrasing from Thomas Hobson himself, but that's not how current usage would have it)

Comment: @FrancisDavey — Depends whether you insist on bespoke tailoring or are happy to settle for "off the peg". And when there are no bespoke tailors for the type of clothes you want you tend to be left with, well, Hobson's choice.

Comment: While this doesn't really describe the OP's situation, I suspect this phrase is what they're thinking of. There's also Sophie's Choice, where both options are totally unacceptable (in the original story she had to choose which of her children would be sent to the gas chamber).

Answer (score 7):

I think **false choice** can be used in OP's context. Here's the description of a book titled "[Women and False Choice: The Truth about Sexism: How to Fight Sexism in the Workplace](https://books.google.co.kr/books/about/Women_and_False_Choice.html?id=cqj8oQEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)"

> As women make life-career choices, they are constrained by **cultural** ideas, images and symbols that create the 'nurturance imperative' in their psyche. Women mistake this learnt nurturing behaviour, of putting others' interests before theirs, for natural instinct and make choices that are not in line with their authentic self. Women, in other words, unknowingly make **false choices**.

(Boldface mine.)

Comment: Given OP's elaboration on the context he's looking for, this seems more correct than the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

From *The Godfather*... "I'm gonna make you an offer you can't refuse."

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offer_one_can%27t_refuse), in the phrase's second sense, an offer that can't be refused is

> (idiomatic) A threatening offer by one party for which the results of failing to accept are so unattractive that the other party is almost compelled to accept.

Answer (score 1):

To me, a word you may want to consider is "non-choice," that is, a choice you're making that is no choice at all (I like to hyphenate it, but in the source I cited, it's non-hyphenated).

> nonchoice (English)
> Origin & history non- + choice Noun nonchoice (pl.
> nonchoices)
>
> An action or situation that is not a choice.
>
> 2009, Elline Lipkin, Girls' Studies: Seal Studies, page 8: The
> “choices” that children may seem to make when left alone with a
> roomful of toys can be realized as nonchoices in light of **how much
> gender scripting they have**, at remarkably early ages, already
> absorbed.
>
> https://www.wordsense.eu/nonchoice/
>
> (Emphasis inserted by me.)

This being said, based on the example in @JK2's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/605123/477625) above, I'd say JK2's answer sounds more correct. On the other hand, I've never heard of the phrase "false choice," but I have heard of the term "non-choice" for situations similar to what you described.

Comment: By George I think you've got it! I've just found a paper which describes a situation very similar to my example as a non-choice

Comment: @SnoringCat, TBF, the very first comment to your question, left by Stuart F, had already answered your question.

Comment: Yes, he did use the phrase, but I wasn't aware of it actually being a phrase without any context. You provided the meaning and context.

Comment: Heh, that's true. No worries, @SnoringCat, hadn't been making a comment about you, but rather, had just been trying to give credit where credit's due .

Answer (score 0):

**no alternative** (*collocation*):

> If you have no alternative, you only have one reasonable choice or
> decision to make.
>
> *I don't want to leave, but I have no alternative.*
>
> [[Cambridge]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-alternative)

An alternative can be heavily *weighted,* or they can be *slanted* (e.g., marriage vs. destitution, in the 1800s) such that there appears to be no real choice in the matter.

> Therefore, Jane had *no alternative* but to accept the proposals, as they came and went, from the rakishly handsome, the extremely amusing, the well-established, the old and decrepit alike.

They speak of *culturally embedded* choices, but sometimes it's practically a matter of life or death.

Answer (score 0):

The term that comes to mind is a **[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity)** which refers to a principle or behavior that is generally observed (in this case, wearing a hijab) and socially enforced without there necessarily being a reasonable justification other than the preservation of the practice (not quite the philosophical definition, however). This distinguishes normative and positive, where the latter refers to principles or behavior that are justified logically in a rigorous manner.

Answer (score 0):

A similar sarcastic slang term for this used in the U.S. Midwest is **volun-told**. This is more related to social obligations than making a choice as such, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Coercion, therefore it is a coerced decision.  The use of Duress and Coercion on a person takes away their free will in decision making.

Answer (score -1):

The term "Double Bind" may apply to your specific example.

Powered by Oxford:

> a situation in which a person is confronted with two
> irreconcilable demands or a choice between two undesirable courses of
> action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Double Bind usually implies that the individual in said bind recognizes both choices as viable, something that doesn't apply to the OP's example of a decision in which one choice is expected via socialization.

Comment: I've added a definition to help, which you're welcome to [edit].  I encourage you you to defend your answer.  Please see the [tour] and [help].

Answer (score -2):

The still used latin phrase 'fait accompli' may be relevant although not sure that it works for the example used by the OP.

**fait accompli** 'noun

> a thing that has already happened or been decided before those affected hear about it, leaving them with no option but to accept it.
> "the results were presented to shareholders as a fait accompli"